# mySQL group very large table to eliminate duplicates

Tags: mysql, group-by, duplicates, mysql-workbench

I have a very large table with about 27 mio. rows and 80 column (mostly float, but also datetime, int and text-values). Basically, there are always 4 rows with unique values except for 2 columns (int, text) that have unequal values. I would like to group those 4 rows to reduce the table size. Which value to keep from the 2 colums with unequal values is not so important at this point. What is the best way to group the data?

As the table is very big it is not possible to overview if the data is always complete, on  i.e. that there are always 4 rows with unique values. Is there a good way how to check this?

Unfortunately, I am beginner with SQL and am very thankful for any hint on how to handle it.

Comment: What is the end goal of 'reducing the table size'? The fact that the row to retain is 'unimportant' is worrying. It *should* matter!!

Comment: It will help us a lot if you [edit] your question to show us 8-12 sample rows. And it will help *you* a lot if you read up on table normalization: 80 float columns is many!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may

```sql
-- Create new table with the same structure
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table;
-- Add unique index by all columns except last two
ALTER TABLE new_table ADD UNIQUE index_name (column1, column2, ... , columnN);
-- Copy data from old table ignoring duplicates 
-- (only one row in each group will be inserted)
INSERT IGNORE INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table;
```

Then you may drop used index, drop old table and rename new one. Or truncate old tabe and copy the rows from new one (using it as temporary).

I hope that no foreign keys and/or triggers on the source table...

Comment: Thanks Akina. This worked for me, except that I had to reduce the nubmer of columns for the index to 16 as I got the Error Code: 1070. Too many key parts specified; max 16 parts allowed.

Comment: @smue If you need to overcome the limit above then you may create generated (if server version allows - virtual) column which concatenates all needed columns and index it.

Answer (score 0):

this query gives you duplicate rows based on the unique columns. replace c1,c2,c3,c4 with the columns which satisfies unity

```
select <unique_columns> 
    from (
    select c.*,
      row_number() over (partition by c1,c2,c3,c4 order by c5) rn
    from myTable c
) t
where rn != 1
```